# Prevent users from closing admin RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, group-policy, administration

I am configuring a Windows 7 computer that will be administered over RDP. The PC is not member of a domain. Is there a way to prevent users from logging in locally and kicking the admin?

I have no control over the users since it will be a public terminal in a store. I am running Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: I'm confused.  This seems like the type of system an admin shouldn't (normally) be logging into during the store's operating hours.

Comment: You're better off using VNC for this as you can 'Lock' the terminal while you're logged on.

Answer (score 1):

With consumer versions of Windows, the RDP link will get kicked off if someone logs in to the local console, and there is nothing you can do about it while keeping within the EULA terms. Server products allow you to do this (i.e. Server 2000, 2003, 2008, 2008R2), and even allow two RDP connections PLUS a locally logged in user!

Having said that, I'm sure there are shady areas on the Internet that will unlock this for you, but it would definitely not be allowed to be posted here if it violates the EULA

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by making a script that disables the local user account when I take over. I have a scheduled task running to enable it again, when I am done.

```
$user = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/kiosk"
$user.userflags = 2
$user.setinfo()
```

Comment: Uhm... what kind of script is this?

Comment: As a follow-up to my previous comment (now that I have a little more experience), it *looks like* a PowerShell script. But I haven't tested it.